# Extra pixels when using w3.css w3-row

Tags: html, css

The following html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
</head>
<body class="w3-red">
    <div class="w3-main w3-content w3-padding">
         <div class="w3-row w3-blue">
             <div class="w3-quarter">
                 <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3images/girl_mountain.jpg" style="width:100%">
             </div>
             <div class="w3-threequarter">
                 <p>Hello World</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

gives the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq8Tw.png). As you can see there is an extra pixel of padding below the image. Is this by design? An error on my part? A bug? Either way I find it very annoying  and would love to know how to get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: what does the w3-main class do? I don't find anything about it in the documentation

Comment: Why not provide the CSS too?

Comment: I think it has to be some kind of browser problem or something like that. I've just tried it in both http://htmledit.squarefree.com and http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro and didn't have any extra pixel.

Comment: sebasaenz: I'm not sure what the w3-main class does. I also couldn't find it in the documentation. I got it from this template: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_food_blog&stacked=h

Comment: Tom: The css is linked in the page You can get it, along with the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_downloads.asp

Comment: sebasaenz: What browser are you using? I get the extra pixel in both firefox 50.0.2 and chrome 55.0.2883.87?

Comment: @daniel I wasn't trying it in the browser, just in the sites I put. anyways, now I've tried it again in the browser and discovered it doesn't have the extra pixel when the window width is < 980 aprox. it surely has something to do with some media query.

Comment: @sebasaenz, right but which browser where you trying those sites in. Those sites give me the same extra pixel in firefox and chrome on linux. I get the extra pixel when shrinking the window until the dynamic layout kicks in and moves the text below the image. I had a friend test it and he gets the extra pixel in firefox, but not in chrome or safari. I submitted a bug to mozilla here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323546 but no reply yet. Thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: @daniel I've got no problem with Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit), the problem was with Mozilla 47. Both browsers are running in linux. you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Credit [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323546) to Mats at bugzilla.

```
img{margin-bottom:-5px}
```

should be

```
img{vertical-align:bottom}
```

in w3.css